# My Gmail keeps freezing

Tags: gmail

My Gmail keeps freezing across all my computers both Mac and PC and different browsers. In Google I get the "Aw, snap!" page. I am not having any problem with my Gmail on my Andriod 'phone.

I tried a previous suggestion about "hiding the people widget" but that didn't help. I have even checked my computer for malware... nothing.

Could my Gmail account have a virus at the source?

Is that possible?

Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Add more details like if you have any lab enabled, if you are using the old chat or Hangouts, versions of OS and browser, if you have any extension, if you have a similar problem with any other Google app (Web Search, Calendar, Drive, Youtube, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the Talk plugin. You can try to disable it:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: `https://talkgadget.google.com/…`

It seems like it might be related to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=964560).

> 1. Click the **gear icon** and choose **Settings**.
> 2. Click the **Chat** tab.
> 3. Choose "Chat off."
> 4. Click **Save changes**.

[*Source*](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/161823)

Should fix the problem.